# Border around render in eevee

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, glass

Is there a way to fix the blue-ish border around the render. I think it has something to do with glass and refraction.[image: Border]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because of Screen Space Reflections.

If my guess is correct, I think there is a refractive mesh covering the camera. The way that SSR works is faking the reflections and refractions by using already rendered objects and transforming them over the surface to imitate the reflection and refraction.

If an object is not rendered, the object does not appear on the reflection or refraction (on these renderers, on path tracing ones like Cycles it does not happen).
There is no way to fix it outside changing renderers, baking the reflection in reflections cubemaps, or removing the mesh on the camera.